# SQL cannot read slash from Excel import

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, excel

I import fuel transactions from an Excel file into an SQL database. 
One column from the Excel is giving me trouble: "product synonym"

```
// Match to product
FuelProductTypeSynonym typeSyn = ctx.FuelProductTypeSynonym.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Name.ToUpper() == row.Product.ToUpper());
if (typeSyn == null)
{
    result.Errors.Add("[" + fileName + "] (row " + currentRow + "): product match not found.");
}
```

If the product synonym doesn't match what's in the database, the program stops. In my case, I have a product "FOOD/BEVERAGE" and it seems like the "/" portion of the name can't be parsed from Excel.

How do I get around this "/" so SQL understands that name?

Comment: Yes, forgot to mention the code is in C#

Comment: How about replace "/" to nothing when getting the column name?  Has to be done in both SQL statement and when finding the Excel column tho...

Comment: inline you will have to do some `string.Replace("/", " ")` it would be nice to